# Errors linking statically the libxml2

Tags: gcc, linker, libxml2

Trying to build statically an application using *libxml2* I have errors like

```
undefined reference to `__imp_xmlTextReaderRead'
```

Removing the `-static` option it works perfectly.

The command I used is:

```bash
gcc -o myapp.exe `xml2-config --cflags` -I /mingw64/include myapp.c `xml2-config --libs` -static
```

Answer (score 0):

To rectify the undefined references to symbols of the form `__imp_xml*`, predefine preprocessor macro `LIBXML_STATIC`
on your `gcc` commandline, like so:

```
gcc -DLIBXML_STATIC -o myapp.exe `xml2-config --cflags` \
    -I /mingw64/include myapp.c `xml2-config --libs` -static
```

**Why?**

You are working with `gcc` on Windows. The undefined references of the form `__imp_xml*` show that your compiler is working in the expectation that your
code will be dynamically linked against `libxml2.dll` at runtime, and to that end will be linked against
that DLL's import library `libxml2.lib` at buildtime. The `__imp_xml*` references will be resolved by
that buildtime import library in proxy for `libxml2.dll`. Your compiler is emitting these references to
discharge DLL import declarations of the form `__declspec(dllimport) xml*` that it finds in the source code,
after preprocessing.

The presence of these `dllimport` declarations proves that the compiler is seeing preprocessed code
*not* intended to enable static linkage against `libxml2`, i.e. linkage against the static library `libxml2.a`,
in which symbols are defined without the `__imp_` prefix.

But you are a specifying static linkage (`-static`). This prohibits the linker from considering import libraries,
even if they are available. The library options that accrue in your commandline by shell-expansion of
`xml2-config --libs` will be of the form `-l xml2 [...]`. In the presence of `-static`, the linker will attempt
to resolve `-l xml2` by scanning its search directories only for a `libxml2.a`, not `libxml2.lib`

Accordingly, the undefined `__imp_xml*` reference errors go away, as you observe, when you remove the `-static` option from your
commandline - because the linker is then at liberty to search for `libxml2.lib`.

Since you want a static linkage, the compiler ought *not* to be seeing preprocessed code destined for dynamic
linkage. But however that problem might be solved for the compiler, the `-static` option will not do it, because
that is a linkage option and does not influence compilation.

The preprocessor does influence compilation and `libxml2` uses the preprocessor macro `LIBXML_STATIC` as a
switch to decide whether the API function declarations in its public header files will emerge from preprocessing
prefixed with `__declspec(dllimport)`, or with `__declspec(dllexport)`, or with neither. The relevant
preprocessor boilerplate is found in the header file `libxml2/libxml/exmlexports.h`, which will be included by
any `libxml2` public header file that you include in your own code.

```
...[cut]...
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)  /* We are on Windows */

#ifdef LIBXML_STATIC        /* We are building for static linkage * 
  #define XMLPUBLIC         /* Our public API symbols are left as seen */
/* Else we are building for dynamic linkage  
#elif defined(IN_LIBXML)    /* If we are building libxml2 itself */
  #define XMLPUBLIC __declspec(dllexport)   /* DLL export our API symbols */ 
#else /* We are building client code */
  #define XMLPUBLIC __declspec(dllimport)   /* DLL import our API names */
#endif
...[cut]...
```

(The comments are all mine.)

That's why you need to define `LIBXML_STATIC` before compilation commences,
per commandline option `-DLIBXML_STATIC`, to suppress the default production of client
code that presumes dynamic linkage.

**But...**

Be forewarned that not *all* undefined symbol linkage errors will necessarily go away with the `__imp_xml*` ones.
If you specify `-static`, then the linker must find static versions of *all* the libraries required by your program:
not just `libxml2`, but also all those that `libxml2` recursively depends on. There are quite a few of
those and it is not unlikely you haven't installed static versions of them all.

If you do have them all, your app will be a very large executable with a very small power-to-weight ratio. You
may or may not have already reckoned with that. If it would suffice for your needs to link `libxml2` itself
statically, but not its whole dependency chain, you can do that too. Consult the [GNU linker's commandline options](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html)
to learn about the relevant linker options `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic`, and also the [GCC's commandline options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)
concerning the option `-Wl` to see how `gcc`  can pass linker-specific options to the linker.

Comment: Hi Mike,

thanks a lot for your clear explanation. I'm going to follow your suggestions but I fear i will have to face also other  issues for other libraries like libiconv libzm and other invoked by libxlm

Comment: You're welcome. Other libraries will not necessarily present the same snag for use in static linkages. It is avoidable for the mingw64 toolchain, but libxml2 chooses not to avoid it and probably has reasons.